# SMB SSH tunnel using putty client painfully slow

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, server-message-block, performance

I've set up an SMB SSH tunnel using putty SSH client to edit my webpages directly from the server on my windows machine (also because my virtuazoo server doesn't allow NFS).

Even setting blowfish as encryption algorithm it goes ULTRA slow (2-3 KB/s)

Any ideas to improve performance?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I always see SMB go slow when connecting to remote networks (either via SSH tunnel or VPN). It's not a great protocol. Using SCP to transfer files or vi/emacs on the server is a better option.

Comment: Set up a batchfile on your windowsn machine to rsync the files up - and only press the button when you are done editing. Editing stuff live sounds like a recipe for disaster. Or coffee cake, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to simply give up on using SMB over a high-latency link.

The protocol preforms badly over high-latency links because it has many operations that require many round trips for acknowledgement.  Tunning TCP over TCP also results in issues will work for both the SSH and the encapsulated protocol.

If you can get the client and server to support SMB2 there is some improvments.  Or you might just want to switch over to sftp, webdav, or some other network protocol.

- [Windows networking performance (SMB/CIFS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/4409/windows-networking-performance-smb-cifs)
- http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MxTunnel as explained here:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/tutorials/SmbTunnel.lsp

A better option is to use WebDAV instead of SMB.
WebDAV is designed to be secure over the Internet.

Comment: I give you a point and my gratitude for introducing me to WebDAV, but MxTunnel is as pointless as ssh since the performance issues are due to the bad support for high network latency on smb protocol, as @Zoredache explained above.